# Query too large mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I`m trying to make a query in robomongo but there seems to be too many results in the query.

```
List<DataObject> list = collection.FindAs<DataObject>(Query.EQ("Item1", "Value1")).ToList();
foreach (DataObject item in list)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

From what i read, i would need to use MongoCursor, but I couldnt find a good example, is there iterate through everything using batches of 1000?

Something like:

```
MongoCursor<DataObject> cursor = collection.FindAs<DataObject>(Query.EQ("Item1", "Value1"));
int batchNumber = 1000;
List<DataObject> list;
while(list = cursor.getBatch(batchNumber);)
{
    foreach (DataObject item in list)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Now I understood i could easily solve this if i dont save it in a list before the foreach by doing :

```
foreach (DataObject item in collection.FindAs<DataObject>(Query.EQ("Item1", "Value1")))
{
     //Do Something
}
```

Comment: `FindAs<DataObject>` returns something that implements `IEnumerable<DataObject>` that you can just foreach over. Are you having problems doing this? Where exactly is your issue? It should be as easy as not calling `ToList` which forces it to get everything in one go.

Comment: Its because i was saving everything in a list before the foreach and than iterating that list, now i see i could solve this by doing `foreach (DataObject item in collection.FindAs<DataObject>(Query.EQ("Item1", "Value1")))`

Comment: That should do the trick. If it does feel free to add an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by not saving the result in a list before the foreach. Like this

```
foreach (DataObject item in collection.FindAs<DataObject>(Query.EQ("Item1", "Value1")))
{
     //Do Something
}
```